# Rails with existing database keeps saying migration pending

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I'm trying to make a new rails project with an existing database.

I create the projects, configure the database.yml and can successfully do a db:schema:dump

This is all based on what I read on this site

http://blog.joelberghoff.com/2013/02/06/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-creating-a-rails-instance-from-an-existing-mysql-db/

And a few others.

After I do the dump, I copied the schema.rb into db/migrate and renamed to 001_createdatabase.rb as indicated in his tutorial.

Everything seems fine.  However I cannot run the site as it tells me i have migrations pending.  and the db:migrate:status indicates its that 001_createdatabase.rb that I created.

So based on that:

- Was creating that 001_createdatabase migration from the schema.rb the right thing to do?
- If it was how do I get rails to understand that it doesn't need to run that one as its already done?
- Where does rails check to see if it has pending migrations.  Obviously it must check the db/migrate folder and compare it to what?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would seem that in order to get credit for having run the migration, you need to actually run the migration.  The migration, `001_createdatabase.rb,` represents the migration that will take you from having an empty database -- no tables, no data -- to having your first version of the database.  When you run `rake db:migrate`, rails checks to see if every file in the db/migrate directory has been run by looking for the numerical part of the migration file name in the schema_migrations table.

In your case, you've not run the migration, there is no entry in the schema_migrations table, so rails thinks, rightly, there is a migration to run.

To fix the issue, you can put the record that the migration has been run into schema_migrations or actually run the migration.  You may need to create the schema_migrations table, rails will create it as needed.

If you want to run the migration, either drop your database (or create a new one -- you can drop the old one when this works), and point your rails application to the new database.  run `rake db:create` and `rake db:migrate`.  When it completes, you should have a new copy of your database, but one that has been created by the rails migration process.  The schema_migrations table should have a record with 1 in the version column.

Comment: Thank you. Very well laid out :)